# Prompt when exit from an activity

Tags: android

I have an activity extending a baseactivity for a common footer nav. Now in a particular activity i was to show an confirmation dialogue to the user when he try to leave that activity by pressing any other nav button. I've tried by onpause and its not working. It doesn't wait for user to press OK in the confirmation box. Basically user must see the box when he click in any other link that that activity.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Now in a particular activity i was to show an confirmation dialogue to the user when he try to leave that activity by pressing any other nav button" -- that is a UX anti-pattern for mobile. The user needs to be able to move to another app without interference (e.g., to respond to an incoming phone call).

Comment: Thts fine, user can move on to receive any calls etc. But when he press any link on that activity screen system will ask him for confirmation

Comment: @user2534310 If you need to ask user something, when you don't have the screen, place a `Notification`.

Answer (score 0):

Just show a dialog to user on whichever link you want to display, say for example, i wrote this following function:

```
private void showExitDialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new Builder(Home.this);
    adb.setTitle("Warning");
    adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit ?");
    adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    adb.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            finish();
        }
    });

    adb.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            arg0.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
    ad.show();
}
```

Then simply call this function inside `onClick` of every link(you say). Hope this would fulfill your purpose.

Comment: The links are in common baseactivity, so it will be show all the time when user press that in any other activity. I need to show them for a particular activity. Also there are some other links too in the activity from where user can switch to another.